# What happened with the YF-16 prototypes?

Tags: fighter, f-16

What happened with the original two prototypes of the YF-16 that were ordered during the Lightweight Fighter Program? Were they converted into combat-capable F-16's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of them are [in museums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16_Fighting_Falcon#United_States_2), YF-16 was a technology exploration and didn’t commit to production.

- YF-16

  - 72-1567 – [Virginia Air and Space Center, Hampton, Virginia](http://www.f-16.net/aircraft-database/F-16/airframe-profile/1/)
  - 72-1568 – [Rome ADC](http://www.f-16.net/aircraft-database/F-16/airframe-profile/2/)
- YF-16A (Full-Scale Development)

  - 75-0745 – Used as a traveling exhibit, on loan from the National Museum of the United States Air Force, Wright-Patterson AFB, Ohio
  - 75-0746 – Pylon-mounted gate guard, McEntire Air National Guard Base, South Carolina
  - 75-0748 – Cadet Area Quadrangle, U.S. Air Force Academy, Colorado
  - 75-0750 – Experimental Aircraft Display Hangar, [National Museum of the United States Air Force, Wright-Patterson AFB, Ohio](http://www.f-16.net/aircraft-database/F-16/airframe-profile/8/)
- YF-16B (FSD)

  - 75-0751 – under restoration at the Air Force Flight Center Museum, Edwards AFB, California.
  - 75-0752 – Frontiers of Flight Museum, Dallas, Texas

Comment: Why would they put aircraft like these in museums? Wouldn't it have been better to use them as trainer aircraft? These aircraft are expensive, it seems strange (when they were new!) to just commit them to become historical exhibits. Couldn't they be modified to be even combat capable?

Comment: @AlphaCentauri It would probably cost more over 25 years to maintain eight unique airframes than to just build the same number of new production F-16s. Unique is bad when it comes to bean-counting.